# Setting HiddenField value in a GridView by javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have following code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal" Width="100%"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="grid_RowDataBound">
    <RowStyle CssClass="gridview" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridviewalt"/>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="" DataField="fld1">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="20%"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="" DataField="fld2">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" ></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblData"  runat="server" Width="250px" Font-Bold="false" Text='<%# Eval("val1") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>

        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="35%" />

        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" Visible="false">
           <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="lblHdnData" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now in javascript, I want to set data in hidden field named **lblHdnData** for a perticular row.

I know `document.getElementById`, and setting the value, but it would be only when HiddenField will not be in GridView. As every row will have different hidden fields and different corresponding data.

How can I do this???

Answer (score 0):

Try use `$('input[name$="lblHdnData"]').val('your data')` if you like to use jquery.